# EntityNotFoundException: Could not retrieve entity of kind ... when commit

Tags: google-app-engine

When my servlet tried to write a record, it encontered the following 
exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Could not retrieve entity of  kind MyEntity with key MyEntity(1318001)
```

even if I have check and ensured that the id 1318001 doesn't exist in 
my datastore. It happened when my servlet commit the transation.

Here is my coding:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = 
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional"); 
EntityManager em = emfInstance.createEntityManager(); 
em.getTransaction().begin(); 
MyEntity ent = new MyEntity(....); 
em.persist(ent); 
log.info(ent.toString()); 
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I can see my ent in the log, but it caused the exception in the commit 
statement. Can somebody please help.

EDIT: @jirungaray @Nicholas, thank you for your comments. The problem was not resolved. I ended up adding `try` and `catch` at the `commit()` to monitor when it happened. Now I've replaced the app with another one and didn't encounter the same problem. Here is the entity if you are still interested.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;
    private String tDate;
    private int stkCode;
    private Text tradeRec;

    public MyEntity() {}
    public MyEntity(int code, String dd, Text trec) {
        this.stkCode = code;
        this.tDate = dd;
        this.tradeRec = trec;
    }
    ..... getter and setter skipped
```

Comment: Could you please provide the source for your entity?

Comment: If this is still an issue, please provide the source for your entity and sample data so that we may attempt to reproduce for ourselves.  If no longer an issue, please post your findings here so this question may be considered solved.